# No output when executing native OS command from Java

Tags: java

I need to run command from my java application and process it's output.
The code is look like this:

```
public static void readAllOutput(){
        try {
            final String cmd = new String("find ~ -iname \"screen*\"");
            System.out.println(cmd);
            Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
//          ps.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException /*| InterruptedException*/ e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I execute this command from OS I have a big output, but in my Java app the output is emty.

Comment: I wonder whether `~`  (user dir) should not better be filled in with `System.getProperty("user.home")`. Also **ProcessBuilder** is a utility class simplifying the handling. Also loop at the same time by reading the error stream in same while.

Comment: Please refactor your code ProcessBuilder

Comment: ~, * etc are expanded by Shell. Your process (find ...) will not do that.  Another approach is to see bash -c <command> as child process

Comment: problem is your using double qoutes, its recommended to use string arrays as in process method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "find", "~", "-iname","screen*"} );
```

or try

```
getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "find", "~", "-iname","\"screen*\""} );
```

inorder to accept arguments as double quotes.